# DB2 printing logs

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

I am using DB2 IBM data studio, and I cannot print logs:

```
create procedure test_ticket 
begin 
     declare stmt varchar(500); 
     DECLARE QTY INTEGER;    
     SET QTY = (select count(*) from test.ticket);
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( QTY );

end
```

> No authorized routine named "DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE" of type "PROCEDURE"
>   having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884,
>   DRIVER=4.18.60

Comment: May be it's not available in your DB2 version?

Comment: @mustaccio my db2 version 9.5.3

Answer (score 0):

As @mustaccio surmised, the `DBMS_OUTPUT` module was not present in DB2 9.5.  It was introduced as part of the Oracle compatibility features in DB2 9.7.

You may also want to note that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` takes an argument of VARCHAR, not INT.